# Что нужно исправить в css файле чтобы изменить размер страницы на мобильной версии сайта

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, когда-то один человек делал мне сайт но потом он где-то потерялся и я осталась один на один со своей проблемой. Суть проблемы в том что на мобильной версии сайта некоторые его страницы открываются не в полном виде. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите гоблин не в низу экрана, а посредине. При этом на некоторых страницах он отображается корректно (снизу) и страница сайта не выглядит как обрубок непонятный. Покопавшись в скрипте я поняла что дело не в отдельных страницах сайта, а непосредственно в css файле, вот только что там искать я не знаю, подскажите пожалуйста какие строки мне нужно найти и что нужно прописать чтобы исправить эту ситуацию. Я понимаю что информация на странице не теряется, здесь больше вопрос в эстетической составляющей. Если на ПК версии всё хорошо, то пользоваться мобильной версией сайта не очень приятно, когда половина страниц это вот такие обрубки. Так же прикреплю ссылки на гугл диск с моими css файлами, может кому-то будет проще разобраться в вопросе взглянув на них напрямую.

Ссылка на гугл диск с css файлом:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EVHwjXV6k01pduo9wZS1qipp6MDsnZNG

Comment: Возможно там нет медиа запросов, или они не корректно работают. Можно посмотреть [тут](https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/)

Comment: Ну я думаю если их нет то на всех страницах сайта были бы вот такие огрызки. Ну, а то что они не так работают я и сама понимаю глядя на мобильную версию сайта. Вопрос не в том корректно или нет, а как это исправить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно футер прилепить к низу страницы. Самый простой способ:

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  min-height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  line-height:1;
}
.full-wrap{
  min-height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.header{
  height:100px;
}
.body{
  height:500px; <!-- указан просто для наглядности -->
  padding-bottom:100px;
}
.footer{
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-wrap">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="body">BODY</div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли, на некоторых страницах сайта при просмотре с мобильных устройств футер болтается где попало. Первый кусок скрипта нужно в css файл вставить я правильно поняла? А второй куда, вы извините меня я в этом деле очень слабо понимаю, то что для многих кажется очевидным для меня ещё пока дремучий лес, но я стараюсь понемногу разбираться)

Comment: @АнастасияКолесник я вам скинул шаблон типичный, которым пользуюсь сам, но вам нужно немного переделать (дополнить верстку), в частности, обернуть SiteMenu и SiteContent  в общий блок (<div class="body">). Справитесь?)

Comment: Боюсь что это я не осилю(( Не могли бы вы мне с этим помочь, я буду очень благодарна. Вот мой css файл https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EVHwjXV6k01pduo9wZS1qipp6MDsnZNG , не могли бы вы его редактировать и сделать то о чём говорите? С другими страницами сайта я уже привыкла работать, но вот с сss никогда дела не имела и даже не лезла туда, так как боялась что-то сломать.

Comment: @АнастасияКолесник одним css это не решить, к сожалению

Comment: А что ещё нужно?

Comment: @АнастасияКолесник доступ к ФТП, дабы слегка поменять верстку. Попробуйте поискать на фрилансе, объяснив задачу. Этот сайт (стаковерфлоу) для подсказок. Я вам подсказал, как можно поступить, дальше ваши действия

Comment: @АнастасияКолесник отписался