# Разместить блок между другими двумя

Tags: html, css, html5

Есть три части в документе: заголовок (*header*), основной контент (*main*) и навигационная панель (*nav*). *Header* должен быть размещён вверху страницы, а *nav* снизу. Между ними всё пространство должно быть заполнено элементом *main*.

В моём случае получается, что *main* заполняет не всю часть между двумя остальными блоками, а они не размещаются в двух концах страницы.

```css
header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

nav {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- Content... -->
</header>

<main>
  <!-- Content... -->
</main>

<nav>
  <!-- Content... -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Так у тебя же просто нет никакого контента внутри секций.
Можешь высоту main в px задать или визуально увеличить его через padding-top padding-bottom
https://jsfiddle.net/9du41b25/2/

Comment: @faradei, да, я неправильно описал проблему, у меня в секции main только один элемент, размеров которого недостаточно, чтобы покрыть пространство. А так, ваше решение вполне подходит.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то вам поможет это - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989510/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-css-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81/989592#989592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение заключалось в том, что нужно было добавить отступ *margin* от края элемента в секции *main* и в секции *nav* присвоить СSS-атрибуту *position* значение *fixed*, чтобы навигационная панель всегда оставалась снизу окна браузера и была доступна, а не находилась в конце всего контента страницы. В общем, я не уточнил, что на странице в области *main* должен быть только один статичный в размерах элемент, поэтому без отступов не обойтись. Если у вас ситуация с различными элементами в секции, то просто добавьте в неё контент, и она автоматически заполнит место между другими разделами.

```css
header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 94%;
  background-color: green;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
 width: 90%;
 padding: 13px;
  background-color: blue;
}

p {
  margin: 80px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- Контент... -->
</header>

<main>
  <!-- Добавьте контент, чтобы секция заполнила место... -->
  <!-- Или, если элемент один, добавьте отступ от его конца -->
  <p>Одинокий текст с отступом</p>
</main>

<nav>
  <!-- Контент... -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

К примеру, дай header и nav по 50 пикселей высоты, тогда main будет height: calc( 100% - 100px). А, и да, это все потому, что контента нет. Потому оно так и есть. В общем, много вариантов есть. Если у тебя контента не много будет, то этот вариант подойдет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Вредный совет, зачем расчет переносить на клиента?

Answer (score 0):

Для правильного отображения нужно всего лишь добавить контент внутрь блока и все пойдет как по маслу

```css
header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  block-size: 75px;
}

main {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height calc(100% - 150px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

nav {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  block-size: 75px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Content...</p>
</header>

<main>
  <p>Просто</p>
  <p>Нужно</p>
  <p>Больше</p>
  <p>Контента</p>
  <p>В самом</p>
  <p>Блоке</p>
</main>

<nav>
  <p>Content...</p>
</nav>
```